# VS .csproj still contains the removed cshtml file which blocks the Build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have removed a View from my Views folder in a ASP.NET MVC project. When pushing it to VSTS DevOps, the Build fails because it can't find the removed file.

I see that in the .csproj file the following:

```
<Content Include="Views\SiteSettings.cshtml" />
```

Which is the file I have removed.

Why is this stil in here? In my Repo the file is completely removed from the Views folder.

How can this be automated that it also removed the entry in the .csproj file?
Or am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

File was still in my soluion, right click Delete and pushing the csproj file to vsts solved the build error.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when after removing a project file you don't explicitly `Save` the project in Visual Studio. In this case Git will only realize the file deletion, but not the project modification itself.

I think if one uses the Git support of Visual Studio then the chance gets smaller, but when using an external tool like `Git` commandline or `GitExtensions` for example, then there is a high chance for this issue.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any workarounds or solutions except for always paying attention to it.

Comment: Ok so for now, deleting the entry from the file is the only solution?

Comment: Probably yes I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Open you project .csproj and remove this line, save, push and publish again.

```
<Content Include="Views\SiteSettings.cshtml" />
```

this will fix your problem about missing file.